# Line Segment Intersection (Crossing only, no touching)

Tags: c++, geometry, intersection

I try to find "Line Segment Crossings". So I want the below function to return true only if both lines really cross each other, not if they start/end on the same points. From what I read there seems to be a kinda "trivial" mathmatical solution to that, but where ever this was mentioned, it wasnt really explained in a way I could comprehend.

Below is a function that correctly detects Segment Intersection, including "touching" points. Is there an easy way to modify it to my needs?

Would really appreciate your help!

```
inline double Dot(sf::Vector2f a, sf::Vector2f  b) { return (a.x*b.x) + (a.y*b.y); }
inline double PerpDot(sf::Vector2f a, sf::Vector2f b) { return (a.y*b.x) - (a.x*b.y); }

static bool LineCollision(const sf::Vector2f A1, const sf::Vector2f A2,
    const sf::Vector2f B1, const sf::Vector2f B2,
    double* out = 0)
{
    sf::Vector2f a(A2 - A1);
    sf::Vector2f b(B2 - B1);

    double f = PerpDot(a, b);
    if (!f)      // lines are parallel
        return false;

    sf::Vector2f c(B2 - A2);
    double aa = PerpDot(a, c);
    double bb = PerpDot(b, c);

    if (f < 0)
    {
        if (aa > 0)     return false;
        if (bb > 0)     return false;
        if (aa < f)     return false;
        if (bb < f)     return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (aa < 0)     return false;
        if (bb < 0)     return false;
        if (aa > f)     return false;
        if (bb > f)     return false;
    }

    if (out)
        *out = 1.0 - (aa / f);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude segment ends, change strict comparisons `<` and `>` in all internal `if's` to  `<=` and `>=` like this:

```
    if (aa >= 0)     return false;
```

Comment: I think comparison floating point numbers on exact equality is not good idea

Comment: @ivan kuklin If you mean comparison with some tolerance - given algorithm is not capable to treat numeric stability problems properly using tolerances. There are special geom. algorithms to overcome these problems (if it is important).